# Centering UL NavBar

Tags: html, css, center

I'm attempting to center my navbar without losing the excess navbar. What I mean is that I want the navbar to show across the entire screen, but have the text in the navbar centered. I have found that if I change the width of the ul{} in the SS to say..28%, it is centered on the screen. But I want to keep it at 100% so that I have the navbar across the whole top. How can I center the text within the navbar?

---

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: NONE;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #449DA2;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px;
 height: 100%
 position: fixed;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body bgcolor=black>
<style>

li { 
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: gray;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: White;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul>

<li class="dropdown"><a href="#home">Info Page</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">East</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Maryland</a>
      <a href="#">Massachusetts</a>
      <a href="#">New England</a>
      <a href="#">New Jersey</a>
      <a href="#">Pennsylvania</a>
      <a href="#">Virginia</a>
      <a href="#">Washington D.C.</a>
    </div>

  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Central</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Illinois</a>
      <a href="#">Indiana</a>
      <a href="#">Michigan</a>
      <a href="#">Minnesota</a>
      <a href="#">Texas</a>
    </div>

  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">South</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Atlanta</a>
      <a href="#">Bowling Green</a>
      <a href="#">Charleston</a>
      <a href="#">Chattanooga</a>
      <a href="#">Jackson</a>
      <a href="#">Memphis</a>
      <a href="#">Miami</a>
      <a href="#">Nashville</a>
      <a href="#">Panama</a>
      <a href="#">Sarasota</a>
      <a href="#">Savannah</a>
      <a href="#">Tallahassee</a>
      <a href="#">WPB</a>
    </div>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">West</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">California</a>
      <a href="#">Colorado</a>
      <a href="#">New Mexico</a>
      <a href="#">Utah</a>
      <a href="#">Washington</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle/codepen or enable the snippet feature in your post while editing it with CTRL+M so that we can see what we're working with.

Comment: Wrap the UL in a DIV and move most of the style from UL to DIV. Technically it is the background color that you want to go across the screen.

Comment: Would recommend you take what @Nawed Khan said - wrap your UL in a container element and use that with the display: block/margin; 0 auto trick. Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deftehsafc/tsv9ddtr/

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @defteH, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to change in your code is the rule for `li`:  Erase `float: left;` and add `display: inline-block`, then the `text-align: center`setting of the `ul` will become effective:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: NONE;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #449DA2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100% position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: White;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#home">Info Page</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">East</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Maryland</a>
      <a href="#">Massachusetts</a>
      <a href="#">New England</a>
      <a href="#">New Jersey</a>
      <a href="#">Pennsylvania</a>
      <a href="#">Virginia</a>
      <a href="#">Washington D.C.</a>
    </div>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Central</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Illinois</a>
        <a href="#">Indiana</a>
        <a href="#">Michigan</a>
        <a href="#">Minnesota</a>
        <a href="#">Texas</a>
      </div>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">South</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Atlanta</a>
          <a href="#">Bowling Green</a>
          <a href="#">Charleston</a>
          <a href="#">Chattanooga</a>
          <a href="#">Jackson</a>
          <a href="#">Memphis</a>
          <a href="#">Miami</a>
          <a href="#">Nashville</a>
          <a href="#">Panama</a>
          <a href="#">Sarasota</a>
          <a href="#">Savannah</a>
          <a href="#">Tallahassee</a>
          <a href="#">WPB</a>
        </div>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">West</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">California</a>
            <a href="#">Colorado</a>
            <a href="#">New Mexico</a>
            <a href="#">Utah</a>
            <a href="#">Washington</a>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```